# How Do I Find Errors and Debug A Cloud Function?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I have created a cloud function that when triggered is supposed to create a VM instance and run a python script.

However, the VM is not being created.

I can see the following message in the CF log, to do with my deployment:

```
resource.type = "cloud_function"
resource.labels.region = "europe-west2"
severity>=DEFAULT
severity=DEBUG
...
```

However, for the life of me, I can't see where to go to actually view the error itself.

I then Googled and found the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663500/google-cloud-functions-crashes-without-an-error-message) about an issue where Cloud Functions is not showing any logs.

Thinking it may be the same issue I added the recommended environment variables to my deployment but still I cant find the error anywhere in the logs.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Here is my cloud function code as well:

```
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
sa_file = "key.json"
zone = "europe-west2-c"
project_id = "<<proj id>>"  # Project ID, not Project Name

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    sa_file, scopes=scopes
)

# Create the Cloud Compute Engine service object
service = discovery.build("compute", "v1", credentials=credentials)


def create_instance(compute, project, zone, name):
    # Get the latest Debian Jessie image.
    image_response = (
        compute.images()
        .getFromFamily(project="debian-cloud", family="debian-9")
        .execute()
    )
    source_disk_image = image_response["selfLink"]

    # Configure the machine
    machine_type = "zones/%s/machineTypes/n1-standard-1" % zone
    config = {
        "name": name,
        "machineType": machine_type,
        # Specify the boot disk and the image to use as a source.
        "disks": [
            {
                "kind": "compute#attachedDisk",
                "type": "PERSISTENT",
                "boot": True,
                "mode": "READ_WRITE",
                "autoDelete": True,
                "deviceName": "instance-1",
                "initializeParams": {
                    "sourceImage": "projects/my_account/global/images/instance-image3",
                    "diskType": "projects/my_account/zones/europe-west2-c/diskTypes/pd-standard",
                    "diskSizeGb": "10",
                },
                "diskEncryptionKey": {},
            }
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "kind": "compute#metadata",
            "items": [
                {
                    "key": "startup-script",
                    "value": "sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip\npip3 install -r /home/will_charles/requirements.txt\ncd /home/will_peebles/\npython3 /home/will_charles/main.py",
                }
            ],
        },
        "serviceAccounts": [
            {
                "email": "837516068454-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
                "scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
            }
        ],
        "networkInterfaces": [
            {
                "network": "global/networks/default",
                "accessConfigs": [{"type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT", "name": "External NAT"}],
            }
        ],
        "tags": {"items": ["http-server", "https-server"]},
    }

    return compute.instances().insert(project=project, zone=zone, body=config).execute()


def run(data, context):
    create_instance(service, project_id, zone, "pagespeed-vm-4")
```

Comment: 1) Why are you embedding a service account in your code? That is unnecessary for Cloud Functions and a very bad idea.

Comment: 2) You have no `try/except` logic for handling errors. Your function will be killed on an exception. Use good programming practices for headless environments.

Comment: 3) You have no logging in your code. Catch errors and then log those errors. In your case also log success and results.

Comment: 4) Why are you getting an image if you are specifying your own `sourceImage` when creating the disk?

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley, why is embedding a service account into cloud functions such a bad idea? Because of security issues? Would you suggest then using the default cloud functions service account?

Comment: Including the actual service account JSON in your deployment is a security risk. Use the Cloud Functions service account.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that you do not see anything in the logs for Cloud Functions is that your code is executing but is not logging the results of the API calls.

Your code is succeeding in calling the API to create a compute instance. This does not mean the API succeeded just the call itself. The API returns an `operation` handle that you then later call to check on status. You are not doing that, so your Cloud Function has no idea that the create instance failed.

To see logs for the create instance API, go to Operations Logging -> VM Instance. Select "All instance_id". If the API to create an instance does not succeed, there will be no instance id to select therefore you have to select all instances and then find logs related to the API call.